# CCLabelBMFont loses tailing characters for each newline characters

Tags: character-encoding, cocos2d-iphone, width, newline, cclabelttf

creating a label this style :

```
CCLabelBMFont *label1_=
[CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"description: -" fntFile:@"comicsans.fnt" width:270 alignment:kCCTextAlignmentLeft];
```

and:

```
[label1_ setString:
@"someText\n and some newline \nand another new line too but this is last"];
```

this string have 2 escape characters for new line as seen.and when I set this Im losing last 2 words
its shown something like this

```
someText
and some newline
and another new line too but this is la
```

so last two letters lost somehow.
what could be a reason for this problem ?
a cocos2d v2.1(stable) bug or Im in a horror film ?if so what should I do ?

\r does same effect as \n
dont know why. may be you know.

if I dont use \r \n escape characters;CCLabelFont String shows correct string.without losing any amount of characters tailing.

so my temporal solution is removing escape characters from string fix problem.
but this not fixes bug for cocos2d v2.1 (stable).
I think CCLabel kind of classes cannot calculate doesnt work stable if there is \n escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I was using CCLabelBMFont to animate text typing.

I realized that whenever the text to type has newlines `\n`, CCLabelBMFont will not type the trailing characters.

I resolved this issue through a simple hack.

First I count the number of newlines in the text to be displayed by `CCLabelBMFont`.

```
NSRegularExpression *regx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n" 
                                                                      options:0 
                                                                        error:nil];

NSUInteger newlinesCount = [regx numberOfMatchesInString:typeString
                                                 options:0
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, typeString.length)];
```

Then I just append some white spaces at the end of the string that I'm about to type. The number of white spaces to add equals to the number of newlines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newlinesCount; i++) {
  typeString = [typeString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
}

// This sets the string for the BMFont, it should now display all the characters
// that you wanted to type originally.
[self.labelBMFont setString:typeString];
```

Tested on cocos2d 2.1